# How can I sync two simultaneous $interval promises in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Struggling to get my head around angular $interval functions.

I want to start a progress bar and a timer at the same time and I want them to complete at the same time. Feels like it should be easy but I can't seem to get them to sync up correctly. Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DMANqi77ud5mN2yCmqt0?p=preview).

I'm struggling to work out the relationship between the countdownSeconds, increment, count and the delay variables. I'm trying to arrange it so that I can just alter the countdown seconds in the config and it will still work. Unfortunately my maths is pretty weak these days.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.19" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>


    <div ng-controller="testController">

        <div class='progressBar-wrp'>

            <div class='progressBar' ng-style="{width : ( pBarWidth + '%' ) }"></div>

        </div>

        <div>{{ countdown }}</div>
        <div>{{ pbVal }}</div>

        <button ng-click="startTimer(); startProgressBar()">Start</button>  
        <div>timerFinish: {{ timerFinish }}</div>
        <div>pbFinish: {{ pbFinish }}</div>

    </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
var config = {
  countdownSeconds: 3
}

function testController( $scope, $interval ) {    

    var timerPromise,
        pBarPromise, 
        timerDone = function(){   
            $scope.countdown = config.countdownSeconds;
            $scope.cancelTimer();   
            $scope.timerFinish = $scope.pbVal; 
            pBarDone();

        },         
        pBarDone = function(){
            $scope.cancelProgressBar();  
            $scope.pbFinish = $scope.pbVal;
        };

    $scope.countdown = config.countdownSeconds;
    $scope.pBarWidth = 0; 
    $scope.pbVal = 0;
    $scope.pbFinish = 0;
    $scope.timerFinish = 0;

    $scope.startProgressBar = function(){

        if ( angular.isDefined( pBarPromise ) ) return;

        var countdownMili = config.countdownSeconds * 1000,
            increment = 1,
            count = 100,
            delay = 30;

        pBarPromise = $interval( function(){
            $scope.pBarWidth  += increment;
            $scope.pbVal      += increment;

        }, delay, count );

        pBarPromise.then( pBarDone );

    };

    $scope.cancelProgressBar = function( ){

        if ( angular.isDefined( pBarPromise ) ) {
            $interval.cancel( pBarPromise );
            timerPromise = undefined;
        }

    };

    $scope.startTimer = function(){

        if ( angular.isDefined( timerPromise ) ) return;

        timerPromise = $interval( function(){
            $scope.countdown--;
        }, 1000, 3 );

        timerPromise.then( timerDone );

    }; 

    $scope.cancelTimer = function(){

        if ( angular.isDefined( timerPromise ) ) {

            $interval.cancel( timerPromise );
            timerPromise = undefined;

        }

    };

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you can't call two timers one after another and expect that they will finish at the same time.

In your case I would use only one `$interval` as a trigger and write something like that:

```
$scope.doTheJob = function(){

        if ( angular.isDefined( pBarPromise ) ) return;

       var currState= 0;

        pBarPromise = $interval( function(){
            currState++;
            $scope.pBarWidth += widthInc;
            $scope.pbVal += widthInc;

            if(currState % 33 == 0){
                 $scope.countdown--;                   
            }
        }, 30, 100 );

        pBarPromise.then( pBarDone );        
    };
```

Demo 1 <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uJt87rIKW6s3jogEDVlm?p=preview)</kbd>

But if you still want to use two `$interval` you need to sync them:

*Modified startTimer*

```
$scope.startTimer = function(){

        if ( angular.isDefined( timerPromise ) ) return;
        var c = 0;
        timerPromise = $interval( function(){
            $scope.countdown--;
            $scope.pBarWidth = 33 * (1 + c);
            $scope.pbVal = 33 * (1 + c);
            c++;

            if(c == 3){
               $scope.pBarWidth = 100;
               $scope.pbVal = 100;
            }

        }, 1000, 3 );

        timerPromise.then( timerDone );

    };
```

Demo 2 <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/K86glIYt1lNyU2aG2ZnZ?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, I knew there must be a way to get it done using one $interval; so much cleaner that way. Thanks again.